# Returning empty collections

Tags: c#, linq

Check out this test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Quick_test
{
   [Test]
   public void Test()
   {
      Assert.AreEqual(0, GetByYield().Count());
      Assert.AreEqual(0, GetByEnumerable().Count());
   }

   private IEnumerable<string> GetByYield()
   {
      yield break;
   }

   private IEnumerable<string> GetByEnumerable()
   {
      return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
   }
}
```

When I write stub methods I generally use the Enumerable.Empty way of doing it. I stumbled across some old code I wrote where I did it the yield way.

This got me to wondering:

- Which is more visually appealing to other developers?
- Are there any hidden gotchas that would cause us to prefer one over the other?

Thanks!

Comment: Not directly related to the question; but as you seem to use MbUnit, there is a dedicated assertion for verifying empty enumerations: Assert.IsEmpty(GetByYield()). It's probably more readable than using the classic equality assertion against the number of items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would prefer any method that delivers the clearest meaning to the developer. Personally, I don't even know what the ***yield break;*** line is does, so returning 'Enumerable.Empty();` would be preferred in any of my code bases.

Comment: I *do* know what yield break does, but I still think Enumerable.Empty() is a much clearer expression of intent.

Answer (score 4):

[Enumerable.Empty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042.aspx) : the documentation claims that it "caches an empty sequence".  Reflector confirms.  If caching behavior matters to you, there's one advantage for Enumerable.Empty

Answer (score 1):

Even faster might be:

```
T[] e = {};
return e;
```

Comment: That bumps us from one-liners to two.  Maybe this would be another alternative along that same thought?

    return new string[0];